# setAttribute doesn't set to LocalStorage

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For some reason I seem to be unable to set an element's value to anything other than text in quotes. As soon as a I go to:

hiddenField1.setAttribute("value", localStorage.curl);

Or anything similar it just fails to load the page and set the attrib.

Full code:

```
var curl = localStorage["curl"];
var username = localStorage["username"];
var password = localStorage["password"];

function fakePost() {  
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("name", "form1");
    form.setAttribute("id", "form1");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "http://SNIPURLlogin&action=login");

        var hiddenField1 = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField1.setAttribute("name", "short");
        hiddenField1.setAttribute("id", "short");
        hiddenField1.setAttribute("value", localStorage["curl"]);
        form.appendChild(hiddenField1);

        var hiddenField2 = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField2.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField2.setAttribute("name", "txtUsername");
        hiddenField2.setAttribute("id", "txtUsername");
        hiddenField2.setAttribute("value", "shane");
        form.appendChild(hiddenField2);

        var hiddenField3 = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField3.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField3.setAttribute("name", "txtPassword");
        hiddenField3.setAttribute("id", "txtPassword");
        hiddenField3.setAttribute("value", "shane");
        form.appendChild(hiddenField3);     

    document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
};
//minify function
fakePostCode = fakePost.toString().replace(/(\n|\t)/gm,'');

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (t) {
  chrome.tabs.create({"url" : "javascript:"+fakePostCode+"; fakePost();"});
});
```

Comment: So finding now that it's a "Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18" doesn't help much so I think this is the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue arises because `localStorage` is specific to its origin. This means that the `localStorage` values on, e.g., `http://example.com` are different from the values on `http://foo.org`. We can say that each origin "has" its own `localStorage`.

You are trying to access the `localStoage` object of a `javascript:...` page (or, at lease the `about:blank` page). Chrome is blocking you from reading or writing to this particular `localStorage` because you're not on a "real" page. Even if Chrome *didn't* throw a security error, what you're trying to do doesn't make a lot of sense -- why would you expect `about:blank`'s `localStorage["curl"]` to be set?

By the way, you can reproduce your error with a single line:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (t) {
  chrome.tabs.create({"url" : "javascript:localStorage['foo']"});
});
```